# ClassNotFound exception in Spring validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to do Server side validation in spring with hibernate-validator in NetBeans IDE.
I am getting following exception.

Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/Filter
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1462)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:860)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)


Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/Filter
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.detectJPA(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:71)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.<init>(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:61)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:106)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:85)
at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:184)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.classmate.Filter
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
```

Registration bean:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RegisterBean {

@NotBlank(message = "First name can not be blank")
@Length(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Enter at least 3 and max 20 letters for first name")
String firstname;
@NotBlank(message = "Last name can not be blank")
@Length(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Enter at least 3 and max 20 letters for last name")
String lastname;
@NotBlank(message = "Please enter password")
@Length(min = 6, max = 20, message = "Minimum password length is 6 and Maximum 20")
String password;
@NotBlank(message = "Please answer security question")
String answer;
@NotBlank(message = "Select one security question")
String question;
@NotBlank(message = "Email can not be blank")
@Email(regexp = "\\\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\\\b" , message = "Email ID is not valid")
String email;

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}

public void setAnswer(String answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView Registeruser(@ModelAttribute("registerBean") @Valid RegisterBean registerBean, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ModelAndView model;
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model = new ModelAndView("index");
    } else {
        boolean registered = userservice.RegisterUser(registerBean);
        if (registered) {
            Userdetails userDetails = this.getUserDetails();
            model = new ModelAndView("/auth/Home", "user", userDetails);
        } else {
            model = new ModelAndView("index","message","Error occured at server please try later");
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you please add spring xml also.

Comment: Please check. I have added web.xml in question.

Comment: Just cross verify in all the xmls mentioned in the web.xml has <context:component-scan base-package="com.customer" />

Comment: This is needed for spring to know which package to scan. Usually it is in applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding validator bean in dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you have not include this Jar `classmate-0.8.0.jar`

so goto this link and download and paste that jar in class path may be it will help.

[dowmload from here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadclassmate080jar.htm)

Comment: i have jar file at class path.

Comment: this one that i have put the link??